# Get the url of webpage currently opened in browser

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, browser

Is there a way (for example winapi method or something) to get the url of webpage which is currently opened in browser in c or c++ program

I have found this C# example
http://grafanimasyon.blogspot.com/2012/10/c-ile-firefoxtan-adresleri-almak.html
but it only works on Firefox and I want it for chrome, IE, and Opera too.

Comment: It definitely depends on what browser you're using - there's no "catch-all" solution

Comment: A browser has several tabs. A desktop can use several browsers at once (e.g. firefox, chrome, and opera). I'm not sure that your question makes a lot of sense. And **why do you ask?**

Comment: In the good old days, Internet Explorer had [DDE commands](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/160957) for this purpose.  Then other browsers started using the same DDE commands, and even mimicking each other's DDE servers.  Then browsers started implementing multiple windows and tabs, which DDE doesn't handle.

Comment: You will most likely have to implement a Browser Helper Object (BHO) for IE, and addon/plugins for other browsers, to actually load code into each browser and hook/monitor its URL changes in real-time.  Then you can communicate that information to your main app using Inter-Process Communication (IPC) techniques when needed.